# Installing whl files - Whl not supported error

Tags: python, pip

I understand there are similar questions here however i have tried all solutions and it still doesnt work. I am using a work computer which has its proxy securities and hence i cant do a direct pip install.

I am trying to install using whl files however i am getting the error `.whl not supported wheel on this platform` . I understand this is got to do with the version of whl file mis matching my python. the admin has installed anaconda env which shows python 3.6.1 and there is also an application python(x,y) which shows python 2.7. I have tried all the versions of whl file but all give me the same error.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: what command(s) are you using?

Comment: pip install and address of the .whl file

Comment: Are you able to downloading the `.whl` file and install it from local? What package?

Comment: no local desktop is where i am trying to install. I am trying packages like 'wordcloud' , 'TextBlob' , no matter what package i attempt and what version it still gives me the same error. This is after i have tried all versions from cp27 to cp37

Comment: Have you tried `pip install textblob` instead of trying to install the `.whl` this should get the PyPi package - EDITED: TextBlob should be textblob

Comment: There is also:

`$ pip wheel --wheel-dir=/tmp/wheelhouse SomePackage`
`$ pip install --no-index --find-links=/tmp/wheelhouse SomePackage`

Comment: i have tried the normal pip install 'packagename' , but that gives me proxy timeout error. hence the resorting to Whl files.

Comment: I assume your IT department has locked down your work computer, if none of those work, you may need to have your IT department install those packages as there is not a whole lot you can do about that.

Comment: What is the full name of the wheel you are trying to install? What is your OS? What does `pip --version` return? What does `python --version` return? What does `python -c "from pip._internal.pep425tags import get_platform; print(get_platform())"` return?